# Relating two objects of different classes

Tags: c#, oop

I'm not sure if the title is clear enough, but I don't know how to exactly describe my problem. I've created a class called Window and I'd like to create another one which would be related to attributes of the class. Let's call the new class Box.

So, we have an object myWindow of class Window, and an object myBox of class Box. I'd like to make sure that the size of myBox would never be bigger than the size of myWindow. As I see it (below):

```
Window myWindow = new Window()
myWindow.CreateBox()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create a method, which would create an object of another class. Simultaneously, their attributes have to be constantly related to each other.

Please, advise me how to implement my idea.

Comment: Do you mean that when properties of the window change, the box's properties have to change as well?

Comment: You can consider using Dependency Injection here

Comment: `Window` would need a mechanism to inform `Box` that it's size has changed. This is what events are for. If `Window` is `System.Window`, for example, `SizeChanged` event that the `Box` would need to subscribe to. Or if `Box` is supposed to represent a model, then you can use binding to bind the size of the window to the size of the box using MVVM.

Comment: @Sweeper yea, it is a part of my problem. I just do not know how to constantly two objects to each other as attributes or methods are related to the object 
@Geeky I will check it out, thanks
@MattBurland maybe I would know how to create a method which would inform `Box` that the size of `Window` has changed. The problem is how to tell the program that THE `Box` is related exactly with THE `Window` and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
     public class Window
{
    private int _size { get; set; }
    public int Size
    {
        get
        {
            return _size;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= MyBox.Size)
                _size = value;
        }
    }
    public Box MyBox { get; set; }

    public Window(int myWindowSize, int myBoxSize)
    {
        if (myBoxSize > myWindowSize)
            throw new ArgumentException("box is bigger than window wah");

        Size = myWindowSize;
        MyBox = new Box(myBoxSize);
    }

    public void UpdateBoxSize(int newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > Size)
            throw new ArgumentException("box is bigger than window wah");
        MyBox.Size = newSize;
    }        
}

public class Box
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public Box(int myBoxSize)
    {
        Size = myBoxSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then create a method under window called 'update box size' or something and do a similiar check to make sure the new size is not bigger than the window.

Comment: A public method called `_getBox`? When you already have a public getter for the `MyBox` property?

Comment: Honestly i was just trying to give him something to work with quickly, ill touch it up for you lot now.

Comment: Updated the code, also - Matt the box was set to private before so its getter was private as well.

Comment: Ok, I get your solution. That's it what I meant. The question is where is a information that the two objects are related with each other. So, `myBox` is independence object and there is not any connection between two objects.

Comment: I mean how to tell the program, that THE `Box` is part of THE `Window` and vice versa

Comment: well defining an instance of the box inside the window class tells the program that the window has a box, you could do the same in the box and create a property for its window.

Comment: do you propose use some `static` instance? It sounds good, isnt it?